# seaborn: limit the number of `col` in relplot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

If I specified `col` arg in `relplot()`, it will plot for each category in `col` column.

But if there were too many categories in `col` columns, the graph would be squeezed vertically, because seaborn will put all plots in one row.

I remembered that there is an argument to solve this problem: something like `max_number_of_col=4`, which puts 4 plots on each row so when the row is full, it will plot on next row.

Unfortunately, I'm not 100% sure whether this is an api of seaborn or not. Please, let me know any api which has this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `col_wrap=` argument to [`replot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html?highlight=relplot#seaborn.relplot)